# EF 4.1 - Insert entity if doesn't exist, use existing one otherwise - how?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Here's a scenario:
There are users, users have skills. If a user specifies new skill, it needs to be added, however if user specifies existing skill - it should link to the existing one. 
So, setup is pretty basic - 3 tables (users, skills, userSkillsLink). It's a web app, but I don't want to add every skills there's in a drop down - so I won't know if skill exists right away. I could check if skill already exists using select, but in web app that's not the best choice - not thread safe.
I can keep a track of which skills already exist in a separate cache, but this problem should be.. very common, so I'm thinking maybe I'm over-complicating, and there's a known solution already.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to solve this with transactional semantics is:

- Make the potentially shared value the primary key of its table so it is guaranteed to be unique
- Query to populate the dropdown and store the results in a local cache
- If the record exists in the cache, reuse it
- If the record doesn't exist, create it

Then you handle concurrency by letting the transaction throw an exception.  In your exception handler you can re-query and use the existing value.

If your transaction dies again (if the record gets deleted), just give an appropriate error message to the user, and tell them to try again.

You can't really do this any other way, since you can't query and commit atomically besides just wrapping it in a transaction, even in a stored procedure.

Comment: This is close to what I do for the time being - I have a list of skills, loaded at startup, and when requesting for a skill, i'm checking against this list if it already exists, yes - load it from db, no - create new one.  The catch with EF is that I can't cache tracked entities, so I'm loading them as NoTracking.

Comment: @Eugene: "if it already exists, load it from db".  You already loaded it on your first query for the list.  Keep that list around if you can, and reuse the entry you find there.  Making sure that the name is the only primary key is also important, otherwise your transaction won't fail when you insert duplicate values.  In which case you don't even have to re-query, because you already have the key: the name of the skill.

Comment: Doesn't work this way - can't cache attached entities. If you do, EF throws "Duplicate key in dictionary" type exception. So it does sound weird, but this cache works only as a reference point, basically, telling me if that item exists, and which operation I need to perform.  This is a web app, and I create/kill DbContext on every request - if I had single DbContext for the life of an app this would work.

Comment: @Eugene: Yeah I can see that not working.  Maybe you could work around this by using the fact that the string *is* the ID, and just insert the ID in your `userSkillsLink` table, rather than the whole `skill` entity.  Not sure, since I haven't tried it out.

Comment: That skill consists from Id and Name properties - so might just as well keep the whole object in cache. Besides, having an int as primary key is generally a better choice.  Anywho, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eugene: I was thinking you should change it, but I think I'll go back on that advice now.  If you want to change the data in a skill (e.g. fix a spelling mistake), and used the natural key (name) instead of a surrogate key (int), then you'd have to update any place it was referenced too.  So yeah, I agree with you.  Although I'd examine your workflow.  If the workflow would be to correct the typos, then you should keep the id column.  If the workflow is to create a new "skill" tag, and move old mappings to the new tag, I suggest you get rid of the id column.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a stored procedure that would take name of the skill as argument, perform the check and insert new record if needed, then return the resulting record (either existing or new).

Then I can map that procedure to a method on `DbContext` and make that method return an entity.

Then I can just call it: `var skill = database.GetSkillCreateIfNone( skillName )`

Comment: You'll still have the same concurrency problems, you'll just be pushing it into a stored procedure instead of in your middle tier.

Comment: Isn't that what transactions were invented for?

Comment: Yes.  You'll have to be transaction aware in your sproc implementation too.  See my answer.  You won't save anything by making this a sproc (except a rare case round-trip on people concurrently creating the same tag), and will increase complexity of debugging your app.

Comment: Remove that "too", and you'll get my point. Sproc uses transaction, the .NET code doesn't bother.

Comment: That's flat out wrong.  The entity framework is always in a transaction (many underlying DBs are always in a transaction, too.  This is why you must commit all non-DDL changes or accidentally lose them).  You just don't know how to use them.  SaveChanges commits.  If an exception is thrown and the context gets disposed, the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Sorry to get so ruffled.  Your suggestion will work, it just isn't a good tradeoff.  Sprocs are best when they save significant round trips in a mainstream access scenario.  They are an optimization.

Comment: Yeah, that's a simpler way.  Can't use it atm, as I'm using SQL CE - no procs support there, but this is temporary, will switch to SQL Server when testing is more or less done.